# Returning value after several Runnable finish

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Currently I have a code as follow :

```
public String getValue()
{
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   // 1st step
   //some logic to retreive code from database returning value
   //doing something with the returned value add it to collection
   builder.append(someString1);
   // 2nd step
   //some logic to retreive code from database returning value
   //doing something with the returned value add it to collection
   builder.append(someString2);
   // 3rd step
   //some logic to retreive code from database returning value
   //doing something with the returned value add it to collection
   builder.append(someString3);

   return builder.toString();
}
```

I've read about Runnable object that can be used to split process into several thread, which going change my code into something like this :

```
public String getValue()
{
     Thread firstTread = new Thread(new Process1());
     firstTread.start();
     Thread secondTread = new Thread(new Process1());
     secondTread.start();
     Thread thirdTread = new Thread(new Process1());
     thirdTread.start();

     // here i got confuse how to determine whether all thread allready finished 
     // before returning builder.toString();
}
//this is internal class
class Process1 implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
      //do something and add to StringBuilder
    }
}

class Process2 implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
      //do something and add to StringBuilder
    }
}

class Process3 implements Runnable
{
    public void run()
    {
      //do something and add to StringBuilder
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that my goal to split the process into several thread?

Comment: It would be simpler to use an ExecutorService.

Comment: You don't mind that the strings could be in different order?

Comment: Is this for Java 8?

Comment: @assylias : any link on this ? is that will also execute the code on separated thread ?

Comment: @Stefan : i'd like to keep it on current order

Comment: NOTE: you should use thread safe StringBuffer instead of StringBuilder in your example...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is not Runnable, but a [Callable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html). Unlike Runnable, a Callable returns a value. This is usually used together with [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) (a thread pool).

It is always good to maintain your threads inside a thread pool instead of manually spawning them like that. This prevents unnecessary and expensive creation of threads. The idea is, instead of calling `Thread.start()`, you submit the instaces of `Callable` to your `ExecutorService` instance with predefined number of threads. Each submission returns a [Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object. Future object allows you to wait for the return value of the Callable instances you have submitted to the ExecutorService.

Here is revised version of your original code:

```
class Process1 implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        return "Some string from this callable";
    }
}
// Insert implementation for Process2 and Process2 Callables
   ...

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

   Future<String> process1Future = executor.submit(new Process1());
   Future<String> process2Future = executor.submit(new Process2());
   Future<String> process3Future = executor.submit(new Process3());

   // It will wait here 
   String processedStringByProcess1 = process1Future.get();
   String processedStringByProcess2 = process2Future.get();
   String processedStringByProcess3 = process3Future.get();

   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   builder.append(processedStringByProcess1);
   builder.append(processedStringByProcess2);
   builder.append(processedStringByProcess3);

   System.out.println(builder.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You use `Callable` which pretty much is a `Runnable` returning a value. And you use an `ExecutorService` instead of creating `Thread` objects yourself.

```
public String getValue()
{
    ExecutorService threaded = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);
    List<CompletableFuture> results = threaded.invokeAll(
        Arrays.asList(this::process1, this::process2, this::process3);
    results.stream()
        .map(Future::get)  // collects the result from each thread
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
private String process1() { return "1"; }
private String process2() { return "2"; }
private String process3() { return "3"; }
```

EDIT:
Note that the output will not be "in different order" because [`invokeAll` returns "A list of Futures representing the tasks, in the same sequential order as produced by the iterator for the given task list"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#invokeAll(java.util.Collection)).

Answer (score 3):

`Callable` suits better for such task cause it returns result.

`ExecutorService` helps to incapsulate threads management.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
    List<Future<String>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    futures.add(executorService.submit(new Process1()));
    futures.add(executorService.submit(new Process2()));
    futures.add(executorService.submit(new Process3()));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (Future<String> future : futures) {
      // handle exceptions
      sb.append(future.get());
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other alternatives for parallelising your work, but to answer your direct question on how to wait for a thread to finish, you can use

```
firstTread.join();
secondTread.join();
thirdTread.join();
```

Comment: Can also be done using Java 1.7's `ExecutorCompletionService<ResultCallable> completionService`